# Styling the file field ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok so Ive been trying to figure out how to style the file field for rails for hours and have found nothing. I would like to style my file field using css and js and so far I am not able to style it in rails. I have listed what I have so far down below.

**form**

```
  <div class="field uploader blue">
    <%= f.text_field :photo, class: "filename", readonly: "readonly" %>
    <%= f.file_field :photo %>
  </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
jQuery("input[type=file]").change(function(){$(this).parents(".uploader").find(".filename").val(jQuery(this).val());});
jQuery("input[type=file]").each(function(){
    if(jQuery(this).val()==""){jQuery(this).parents(".uploader").find(".filename").val("No file selected...");}
});
```

Works using **html** not rails

```
<div class="uploader blue">
  <input type="text" class="filename" readonly="readonly"/>
  <input type="button" name="file" class="button" value="Browse..."/>
  <input type="file" size="30"/>
</div>
```

Are there any helpers for the file field in rails or a way where I can split the upload & input button using a helper so i can get the code just like the html code?

Comment: Have you looked at the HTML that Rails produces?

Comment: @varatis yes its produces this`<input id="upload_photo" type="file" name="upload[photo]">`. I do not see a button tag that I can style individually.

Comment: Does this page help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037154/customising-the-look-of-f-file-field-in-rails

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson I checked that out before posting this and It didnt seem to solve me problem. I wanted to create a helper or find a way to split the file field int multiple parts such as field, button etc.